# Swap and Return Char Array from the Function

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, char, swap

I know there are many questions related to my this question but still facing problem. I'm using the function to swap array mean when I input ABCD it shoudl return DCBA. Code is below check where is problem. Is there a way to pass second empty array as reference? **Swap is working fine, but array is not returning fine. I just want to solve this code related to [characters array]. Don't discuss about string etc.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 80
using namespace std;
char* reversit(const char a[]){
    int size=strlen(a)-1;
    char b[MAX];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(a); i++){
        b[size--] = a[i];
    }
    b[i]='\0';  
    return b;
}
int main(){

    char a[MAX];
    char b[MAX];
    cin.get(a,MAX);
    b=reversit(a);
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can indeed not return arrays. That's one big problem with them.

If you *really* want to use `char[]`, you can just pass the output array as an extra parameter:

```
void reversit(const char *a, char *b){
    int size=strlen(a)-1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(a); i++){
        b[size--] = a[i];
    }
    b[i]='\0';  
}
```

Note that `char[]` and `char*` is the same as a function argument.